# No NIC in Windows 10 VM

Tags: centos, virtualbox

I am trying to create a headless Windows 10 VM on my CentOS host.

When I log into the VM, I don’t see any network adapters listed in ncpa.cpl. I do see an "Other" Ethernet controller in the Device Manager. I did the following:

1. Ran ifconfig on the host -> note the name of the NIC with an IP (enp3s0, in this case)
2. Ran VBoxManage modifyvm "vm1" --nic1 bridged --bridgeadapter1 enp3s0
3. Started the VM -> still no NIC

If I look at the VM properties, I see:

> NIC 1:           MAC: 0800278C0EB6, Attachment: Bridged Interface 'enp3s0', Cable connected: on, Trace: off (file: none), Type: Am79C973, Reported speed: 0 Mbps, Boot priority: 0, Promisc Policy: deny, Bandwidth group: none

I am running 5.2.6r120293.

Any thoughts on what I’m missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add "--bridgeadapter1 enp3s0" to the command. It works now.